# 「が分かるようにできる」についての質問

Tags: usage, transitivity, construction

## 日本語

> 32変数のd次方程式って32個があったら大抵変数を分かるようにできます。

この文を書いてたんですけど、間違えてたと思います。「何々が分かるようになる」を使えるのは分かりますが、「何々を分かるようにする」ってあってますか？僕の原因でそのことが分かるようになったみたいなことを言いたいです。

## 英語

First, for accurate context, a mathematically solid version thanks to @JansthcirlU:

> Regarding polynomial equations in 32 variables of degree d, if we have 32 of them (such equations) we can find the solution to that system of equations containing them (find the values of each of the variables that satisfy the system of equations containing them).

If possible I'd like to keep the current structure of the Japanese line (see the Japanese version). It doesn't have to be in mathematics specific language. In fact, I prefer to write it in plain language, so the roughly equivalent English version which, albeit mathematically inaccurate, reflects the way I'd like to say it in Japanese, is:

> In terms of d-th degree polynomial equations with 32 variables, if we have 32 of those equations, very likely we will be able to calculate the variables.

I would like to say the above sentence. I used "solve" in the English version, and I know I could use 「解く」, but I'd like to use this structure if possible「が分かるようにできる」. I understand that 「何々が分かるようになる」 works. But how should I use「が分かるようにできる」to indicate that "*we can make* them clear" and to imply it is an active process on *our* part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118270/discussion-between-jansthcirlu-and-eddie-kal).

Comment: No, we really don't have to continue this at all. Please just ignore the mathematical inaccuracy of my sentence for a second. I have made it abundantly clear mathematic accuracy is not a concern of this question. This is not Math SE. This is Japanese SE. Your questions in these comments have really skewed the focus. I think the original Q has made things pretty clear. But even your first question, which asked me to choose between "a polynomial with degree 32" and "a polynomial with 32 coefficients" when the Q clearly says "32変数" "方程式って32個", started off as a misunderstanding of the Q.

Comment: You're right that I've completely misunderstood and misinterpreted your clarification that this was in fact about a 32-variable polynomial. However, there's still something I don't quite understand in the original English comment which is what I wanted to chat about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

趣旨からすると、おそらくこう言うのが一番適切なのではないかと思います。

> 32変数のd次方程式だったら、32個あれば大抵すべての変数が求まります。

数学の文脈では、「値を見つける」という操作を表す一番基本的な表現として「求める」を使います（これは中学生でも知っている意味です）。そしてこの用法から派生した「[求まる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B1%82%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B/)」という動詞が、「値が算出される」という意味で数学ではごく普通に使われます。これは自動詞ですが、（数学の意味での）「求める」というのはそもそも「誰かが計算をする」という行為が前提にあるので、「計算した結果、解が分かる」という意味まで含んでいます。ちなみにより普通の日本語として「求められます」と言っても同じです。

以下補足ですが、

- 「～って」はここではあまり自然には聞こえません。「～って」を使う時は何か話し手に表現したい感情がある場合なので、最後に何らかのモダリティ要素（～でしょう、～ですか、～かも、～じゃん…）か終助詞が必要です。
- 上の文で「～だったら」を使いましたが、これは条件というよりも、「～の場合は」と同じ意味になります。「～であれば」としてもいいですが、直後の条件節とかぶるとわかりにくいので、二つを違う表現にしました。